# Chrome service 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'split' error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue with the chrome webdriver service.I use webdriver manager to get the correct version of the driver but it has a this Attribute Error.

the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd


URL = "https://iol.invertironline.com/mercado/cotizaciones/argentina/obligaciones%20negociables"
URL2 = "https://www.byma.com.ar/tipo/obligaciones-negociables/"

# Create webdriver object
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
#options.add_argument("--headless")
# selenium 4
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
# Get the website
driver.get(URL)

# Make Python sleep for some time
sleep(2)
# Read and Convert Web table into data frame
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'cotizaciones_length'))
# select by value
select.select_by_value('-1')

table = pd.read_html(driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//table[@id='cotizaciones']").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]

print(table)
# print(len(table))
```

the Error:

```
AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'   File "C:\Inversiones\prueba2.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Do you have any idea why i have this issue?

Comment: I think the `webdriver.Chrome()` line is expecting both `service` and `options` parameters. You created `options` but never used it. Try `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)`.

Comment: Also, as of Selenium 4.6+, Selenium now has a driver manager built in so you no longer need `ChromeDriverManager()`. See https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/ for more info.

Comment: JeffC the issue is not with the options, because I tryed alse with option = options and i have the same error. The issue i think it could be with the chromeservice() function.

Comment: Comment out everything driver related including options and just use the simple `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`... does that work?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work.

Comment: What error do you get with the simple version above?

Comment: Is always the same error:
AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'   File "C:\Inversiones\prueba2.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You can't get that error with the simple driver declaration that I mentioned. The error shows that you are still using ChromeService, etc.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me, which indicates that this could be: 1. A bug that was fixed outside of your control 2. You are on an old version of Selenium of chromedrivermanager